# How to separate style elements in an Epilog?

Tags: plotting

I have this epilog:

```
Epilog -> {
  Dashed, LightBlue, Line[{{basexhat, 0}, {basexhat, 600}}], 
  Dashed, LightBlue, Line[{{lastxhat, 0}, {lastxhat, 600}}], 
  Text[Style["Yearly rent per sq m", FontFamily -> "Cambria", 
    Opacity[0.7], 12], Scaled[{.5, .9}]]
  }
```

But it applies the Dashed and LightBlue to the text too, what can I do to make the Dashed and LightBlue only apply to the lines?

When I try to close them in groups:

```
Epilog -> 
 {Dashed, LightBlue, Line[{{basexhat, 0}, {basexhat, 600}}]}, 
 {Dashed, LightBlue, Line[{{lastxhat, 0}, {lastxhat, 600}}]}, 
 {Text[Style["Yearly rent per sq m", FontFamily -> "Cambria", Opacity[0.7], 12], Scaled[{.5, .9}]]}
```

The whole graph loses its properties and gives weird results.

Comment: use {   } to enclose the group.

Comment: @cvgmt Check my edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use braces to introduce scopes for the styles, so something like the following should work:

```
Epilog -> {
  {
    Dashed, LightBlue, 
    Line[{{basexhat, 0}, {basexhat, 600}}], 
    Line[{{lastxhat, 0}, {lastxhat, 600}}]
  }, 
  Text[Style["Yearly rent per sq m", FontFamily -> "Cambria", Opacity[0.7], 12], Scaled[{.5, .9}]]
 }
```

This way, the styles will only be applied to the things inside the inner `{…}`.